# Why is showing this error? How to solve this error?

Tags: flutter, console, version, publish, playback

I have uploaded an apk file in google play console account. Here I am getting this error. [image]

```
defaultConfig {
  
    applicationId "com.abc.app"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 25
    versionName "1.1.12"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make compilesdk version to 31
android {
compileSdkVersion 31
defaultConfig {
// ...
targetSdkVersion 33
// ...
}
// ...
}